# Actionscript: SWF file does not record data to txt, while the compiler does

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to create a psychological experiment in ActionScript. The performance of the participants is to be stored in a separate .csv file. I have written this code (apparently, instead of "This is the text to write" there is going to be a data array, but the problem appears with this code on equal parts)

```
import flash.net.FileReference;
import flash.events.Event;

var hint:String = "Please give a name for the file";
var labelling:String;

experiment_label.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, enter_pressed)

function enter_pressed (event:KeyboardEvent):void{
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        labelling = experiment_label.text;

        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,saveFile);
        var ss:String = "this is text to write";
        var fileRef:FileReference;
        fileRef = new FileReference();
        function saveFile(event:Event):void
            {
                fileRef.save(ss, labelling+".csv");

                removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, saveFile);
            }
    }
}
```

The problem I am facing is as follows: when I run it in from under Flash, it operates perfectly, and the save window does pop up. However, if I run an .swf file separately, it just ignores saving command.

Could you kindly suggest, what can I do? Or maybe I should use a different approach to saving altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You current code will give you an `Error #2176` (use a `try` ... `catch` to catch it) because [`FileReference.save()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#save())

> is not called in response to a user action, such as a mouse event or keypress event.

To avoid that, you have to remove the `Event.ENTER_FRAME` event listener, even you don't need it :

```
function on_KeyUp(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (event.keyCode == 13)
    {
        save_File();
    }
}

function save_File():void
{
    try
    {   
        var fileRef:FileReference = new FileReference();
            fileRef.save('some text here', 'my_file.csv');
    }
    catch (e:Error)
    {
        trace(e.toString());
    }
}
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: Thank you a great lot! It actually did help! Unfortuantely, I am a newbie, and I cannot vote for your answer, but my deepest gratitude is with you!